# How to wrap and replace one of the default components in the ASP.NET 5 configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration, asp.net-core

ASP.NET 5 (RC1) gives us a completely new configuration model, where we add/replace configurations to a collection of `ServiceDescriptor` objects. Replacing a default implementation is straightforward, for instance:

```
services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(
    new MyHttpContextAccessor()));
```

However, I'm having trouble finding a way to extend an existing registration with extra behavior (through decoration). In other words, I want to replace the built-in version with a custom one that uses the built-in version internally. It is of course very common to extend framework behavior this way. For instance:

```
// How to get the instance here???
IHttpContextAccessor original = 
    services.Last(service => service.ServiceType == typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));

services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(
    new HttpContextAccessorDecorator(original)));
```

Do note that the use of the `IHttpContextAccessor` is just an example, but does effectively show the problem. The `services` collection contains `ServiceDescriptor` objects, and in the case of the `IHttpContextAccessor`, the `ImplementationInstance` and `ImpementationFactory` properties are empty, making it impossible to get that original instance. We can't inject an `IServiceProvider` into the decorator to delay the registration, because once we request an `IHttpContextAccessor` inside our decorator, we will get that same decorator back, which will cause a stackoverflow exception.

Funny thing is that with MVC 5 and Web API, this is actually *really* straightforward to do.

How can I achieve the same with ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* accomplish this, in a **hacky** way, by building an 'intermediate' service provider. You can then retrieve an instance of the original implementation and use it when creating your own instance:

```
var innerSp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var original = innerSp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddInstance<IHttpContextAccessor>(new HttpContextAccessorDecorator(original));
```

This requires the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package (not the `Abstractions` one) since it uses the internal `ServiceProvider` implementation.

Of course, this is a awful solution and I agree we need something better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I can see now, what you are describing is actually the only way of solving this with RC1. However, even your approach is flawed, which not only makes it 'hacky', but really makes the current design problematic. I created an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3739) to notify Microsoft about this issue. One of my comments on that issue also describes why this approach is actually flawed.