# System.Net.Primitives.dll Cannot find the file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

In ApsNetCore RC2 web application i'am having a problem injecting IHttpContextAccessor

I have a class HttpContextService which implements IHttpContextAccessor and in stratup.cs I added it like this `services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextService>();`

And when I run the project it stoppes without showing errors, so I looked into log and found this: 
**'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.0-rc2-3002702\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll**

Does someone has same problem or solution to fix it?

Edit:
I tried to activate the service in two ways:

```
    //this one throws and error Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'EPTV.Services.HttpContextService'.
        services.AddTransient<HttpContextService>();
//and with this one the project dont even start like I explained before
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextService>();
```

The service looks like this:

```
public class HttpContextService : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get { return HttpContext; }

            set { HttpContext = value; }
        }

        public HttpContextService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public HttpContext GetHttpContext()
        {
            return _accessor.HttpContext;
        }
        public string GetHeader(string value)
        {
            return _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[value];
        }

        public string GetUserAgent()
        {
            return _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        }

        public string GetHost()
        {
            return _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
        }
    }
```

This is the exception I get:

**Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Additional information: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor'.**

Comment: What does your `project.json` look like?

Comment: PDB files are not critical for the execution of the software, so I'm not sure the error you are posting is relevant to the issue you are facing.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "System.Net.Primitives" in dependencies of your project.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.11-rc2-24027"
  }
```

Comment: Nope. It doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Decorating ASP.NET Core services is not supported, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/340) for discussion.

A "hacky" solution to your problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34207679)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

It seems that in AspNetCore rc2 you have to register IHttpContextAccessor like this in startup.cs `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

And then you will be able to inject IHttpContextAccessor in controllers or other services